# insert element after another with multiple containers

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="div one">
 <div class="text">One</div>
 <svg>object</svg>
</div>
<div class="div two">
 <div class="text">two</div>
 <svg>object</svg>
</div>
<div class="div three">
 <div class="text">three</div>
 <svg>object</svg>
</div>
```

And I would like to insert text div after svg object, using this:

```
$('.div .text').each(function(){
 $(this).insertAfter('.div svg');
});
```

but the output is like: [codepen](http://codepen.io/KareemAtif/pen/XmKRZv)

```
<div class="div one">
 <svg>object</svg>
 <div class="text">three</div>
 <div class="text">two</div>
 <div class="text">one</div>
</div>
<div class="div two">
 <svg>object</svg>
 <div class="text">three</div>
 <div class="text">two</div>
 <div class="text">one</div>
</div>
<div class="div three">
 <svg>object</svg>
 <div class="text">three</div>
 <div class="text">two</div>
 <div class="text">one</div>
</div>
```

I suppose `each()` select each element inside its div, not all elements and repeat them after target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the sibling `svg` element to the current `.div .text` element and insert after that. Try this:

```
$('.div .text').each(function() {
  $(this).siblings('svg').after(this);
});
```

[**Updated codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKWdRX)

Comment: thanks, that is the simplest, and that's how I update it: http://codepen.io/KareemAtif/pen/XmKRZv

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that. The append function always places the Element on the last position of the Wrapping Element:)

```
$('.three').append($(this));
```

Comment: Yes, append was much better solution. Thanks

Comment: @Kareem Glad I could help. Ok, so everyone knows it's correct upvote it and mark as Soltion :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each `.div` as below:

```
$('.div').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.text').detach().insertAfter($(this).find('svg'));
});
```

and `detach` it from its original place and `insert` after that particular `div`'s `svg`. Thus you need to find `svg` with `$(this)`

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/qONmQN)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```js
$('.div .text').each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
  // or  $(this).next().after(this);
});
```

```css
.text {
  font: bold 21px/2em Arial
}
svg {
  background: #bbb;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div one">
  <div class="text">One</div>
  <svg>object</svg>
</div>
<div class="div two">
  <div class="text">two</div>
  <svg>object</svg>
</div>
<div class="div three">
  <div class="text">three</div>
  <svg>object</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right, if you want to remove `.text` element and place it after svg element, use this :

```
$('.div  .text').each(function() {
 // get the closest parent and find its child(svg)
 var target = $(this).closest('.div').find('svg');
 // insert after svg(.text)
 $(this).insertAfter(target);
});
```

Updated [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/metallurgical/pen/KdMmbJ)